# Explain the hex of the OID portion of an SNMP GET REQUEST message

Tags: c, network-programming, snmp

So I've been working on coding the C version of an SNMPGET request on linux. I open a UDP socket, form the message, and send it out only to continually get a reply saying the OID isn't found. The OID I was using was:

1.3.6.1.2.1.1.1.0
Hex:
00 03 06 01 02 01 01 01 00

After running tcpdump on the packets being sent by snmpget, I realized that even with the same OID the packet being sent actually contained the hex:

2B 06 01 02 01 01 01 00

When I tried that hex with my program it worked. So, question is, why is it 2B instead of 01 03? I've looked everywhere but I can't wrap my head around the logic of it. It seems that every SNMP get message is sent this way where the iso.org translates to 2B but I've yet to see a reason why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First two numbers (`1.3` in your case) are encoded differently. The calculation will be:

`1`***40** + `3` = 43(dec) = 2B(hex).

That's the reason for your `2B`.

Read [this](https://www.snmpsharpnet.com/?p=153) for more info.
And [here](https://www.viathinksoft.com/~daniel-marschall/asn.1/oid-converter/online.php) is an online tool to encode/decode.

Comment: Thank you! That makes a lot more sense now.